# Process type для telegram бота(Heroku Procfile, Java)

Tags: java, telegram-bot, heroku

В документации Heroku не нашёл исчерпывающей информации о том, какие бывают `process types` и с чем их едят.
Понял только, что их минимум три:

- **web**  - считается особенным, потому что перенаправляет http запросы приложению
- **worker** - ?
- **clock** - ?

Объясните, пожалуйста, для чего предназначены `process types` со знаками вопроса?
И какой `process type` выбрать для `telegram` бота? Я думаю, что `web` не подойдёт, так как приложение само должно слушать `telegram api`, а не принимать запросы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Со назначением `process types` до конца я не разобрался. Могу только сказать, что для моей задачи подошёл `worker`. Далее о том, как запустить `telegram`-бота на `Heroku`.

Сначала я пробовал писать в `Procfile` что-то вроде `web: java -jar target/app.jar`. Работало, но не долго. А именно, 3 минуты, которые `Heroku` даёт `web`-приложениям на запуск(1 минута + 2 повторных попытки).

Так работает:

Procfile:

```
worker: sh target/bin/workerBot
```

Т.е. будет запускаться `sh` скрипт, генерируемый с помощью `Maven` плагина `appassembler-maven-plugin`. В скрипте описан запуск скомпилированного `jar`. Имя запускаемого класса указывается между `<mainClass></mainClass>`, имя скрипта между `<name></name>`

pom.xml:

```
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>com.home.server.TelegramBot</mainClass>
                        <name>workerBot</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Немного про последующий `deploy`. Если вы вносите изменения находясь не в ветке `master`(как я, работал в ветке `heroku`) то выполнять `push` на `Heroku` необходимо именно в ветку `master`, иначе не запустится авто-сборка проекта. Я делал так: `git push heroku heroku:master`.

После того, как ваш проект развернётся на сервере, выполните: `heroku ps:scale worker=1`. Это как кнопка "Старт", если вдруг `Dyno` ранее упал, это его запустит, если он жив - ничего не изменится. Я читал, что этот шаг многие пропускают - приложение не работает. Я не стал исключением. Всем работающих ботов

Comment: А в чем может быть проблема, если скрипт плагином не генерируется?

Comment: Проделал в точности как описано здесь. 1. В Procfile прописал `worker: sh target/bin/workerBot` - http://prntscr.com/rn56rl.
2. В pom.xml добавил плагин и указал там свой класс - http://prntscr.com/rn572k.
3. Но после деплоя получаю "*Error: Could not find or load main class src.main.java.server.Bot*". Где я торможу?) Пробовал заменить `worker: sh target/bin/workerBot` на `web: sh target/bin/workerBot` - тоже самое. А при вводе команды `heroku ps:scale web=1` получаю следующее - http://prntscr.com/rn5o5d

Answer (score 0):

Если не получается, можно попробовать заменить `worker: sh target/bin/workerBot` на `web: sh target/bin/workerBot`. И запустить в `git` команду `heroku ps:scale web=1`. Для меня сработало.