# Как запустить Java приложение (Telegram bot) на Heroku?

Tags: java, telegram-bot, heroku

Делаю деплой через **Github**. По информации из [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/618753/process-type-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-telegram-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0heroku-procfile-java) вопроса в **Procfile** добавил `web: sh target/bin/workerBot` (вместо web пробовал и worker). В **pom.xml** добавил необходимый плагин и указал в нем свой класс - http://prntscr.com/rndp26.

Структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но все равно получаю "*Error: Could not find or load main class src.main.java.server.Bot*"

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Попробуй в качестве пути к мейн классу писать просто server.Bot

Comment: Не читаете учебники, а потому не отличаете путь в исходниках от квалифицированного имени пакета.

Comment: @NarasuOo спасибо тебе большое! Закрутилось.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я только учусь) Но тоже спасибо за отклик. Сейчас прочту информацию на эту тему.