# Почему не работает Telegram бот на heroku

Tags: java, telegram-bot, heroku

https://github.com/GeorgeLapp/HerokuBot - вот мой бот
Так сам по себе он работает но при загрузке на heroku нет,

думаю дело в pom.xml  или Procfile. В логах пишет :

```
2020-05-24T09:27:56.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user 
2020-05-24T09:28:13.394830+00:00 app[api]: Deploy aba3ec75 by user
2020-05-24T09:28:13.394830+00:00 app[api]: Release v14 created by user 
2020-05-24T09:28:15.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

включил
в логах

```
2020-05-25T19:31:54.669275+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user george.lapp.java@mail.ru
2020-05-25T19:32:00.787801+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2020-05-25T19:32:00.801571+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2020-05-25T19:32:01.182785+00:00 app[web.1]: Expanding Bot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar into /app/target/tomcat.59475/webapps/expanded
2020-05-25T19:32:01.182800+00:00 app[web.1]: Adding Context  for /app/target/tomcat.59475/webapps/expanded
2020-05-25T19:32:01.790832+00:00 app[web.1]: May 25, 2020 7:32:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
2020-05-25T19:32:01.790840+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-59475"]
2020-05-25T19:32:01.825408+00:00 app[web.1]: May 25, 2020 7:32:01 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
2020-05-25T19:32:01.825410+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2020-05-25T19:32:01.830558+00:00 app[web.1]: May 25, 2020 7:32:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
2020-05-25T19:32:01.830559+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting service Tomcat
2020-05-25T19:32:01.831751+00:00 app[web.1]: May 25, 2020 7:32:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
2020-05-25T19:32:01.831752+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
2020-05-25T19:32:02.056512+00:00 app[web.1]: May 25, 2020 7:32:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
2020-05-25T19:32:02.056519+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: No global web.xml found
2020-05-25T19:32:02.375597+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-25T19:32:02.896803+00:00 app[web.1]: May 25, 2020 7:32:02 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
2020-05-25T19:32:02.896812+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2020-05-25T19:32:02.931177+00:00 app[web.1]: May 25, 2020 7:32:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
2020-05-25T19:32:02.931179+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-59475"]
```

Comment: Так а вы его включили? `heroku ps:scale web=1`

Comment: Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:Free

Comment: все равно не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать как написал [`Lurking Elk`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/185684/lurking-elk) в своем ответе здесь: [Process type для telegram бота(Heroku Procfile, Java)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/618753/process-type-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-telegram-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0heroku-procfile-java)

Учтите, что в вашем pom.xml указано "org.example",а на данный момент в проекте нет именования пакета.
Почитайте про тег  здесь: https://www.apache-maven.ru/project-file.html